# Pass Data to Master Template

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

I customize django admin for showing a custom nav-bar on the top. So I add, to my adminClass (in admin.py), a method for overriding `changelist_view` and pass a list of objects (inside of `changelist_view`) which the template recover it and showing in the nav-bar.

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}                 
    mygetModels = getModels()
    extra_context["modelsTables"] = mygetModels.getTablesModels()
    return super(SrcComscoreInformeAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

When I call a specific table in Django, is working perfectly but if I try to add a new record (so the url will be `/admin/db/table_name/add/`), this template is using my custom nav-bar (I define it in my overridden `base_site.html`) as I want, but this template (add option) is not getting the list which I suppose to send from the view. Should I change/override another view? How can I modify the correct view for passing a list of object as I did for `/admin/table_name/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`changelist_view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.changelist_view) is used to display the table of model items.

If you are adding a new item or editing an existing item, then you need to override [`add_view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.add_view) or [`change_view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view) respectively.

Comment: That was the idea. 
Thanks mate today I cant see anything, bad day... But you make me smile. Thanks!!